# how to start mining with FPGA

Tags: miner-configuration, fpga

I found that in my university there are some FPGA's available to test and to play with. I am a software/web programmer and I have never been working with verilog or whatever is used to program FPGA.

So is there a nice tutorial which explains how to start mining using FPGA. I do not want to create a fancy 2 - 10 connected FPGAs to run mine for profit, but I just want to start one FPGA and to see how it is working and what speed it is giving me.

I have checked the question: [What software/hardware is required to mine with an FPGA?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/what-software-hardware-is-required-to-mine-with-an-fpga), but it does not provide information, I needed.

P.S: I also have seen this post: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9047.0 , but I hope to hear from someone who started to mine by himself and can share his experience.

So is there an easy to use tutorial for a not microsystem guy who wants to test mining. Or this is so complicated?

P.S. The vendor is `Xilinx`.

I have two different models:

- The model for the simple one is `Spartan 3E`
- The model for the advanced one is `Virtex5`

Comment: The bitstream that gets loaded is not universal among FPGAs.  Bitcoin StackExchange might not be a great place to get pointed in the right direction.  Perhaps try the Custom Hardware board on the forum? http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=76.0

Comment: What vendor/model of FPGA are you using?

Comment: Thanks @NickODell I updated the question with FPGA details

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mine with FPGAs?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3539/how-do-i-mine-with-fpgas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So is there a nice tutorial which explains how to start mining using FPGA.

Not really, not a "starting from scratch" one.

> Or this is so complicated?

Yes, it is quite complicated - in order to work with FPGAs, some additional skills on top of software are required.  You need to understand logic design and some (fairly basic) electronics in order to make a successful FPGA.

However, as a learning project, if it's something that interests you, I'd say it's worth a go - you'll learn a lot, but it won't be a quick-and-easy learning experience :)

But start small - first off, write an FPGA which just flashes an LED on and off slowly - that enables you to learn lots of the low-level details without a complex logic design going on.  The FPGA equivalent of "Hello World"!

---

EDIT:

If you've already done some FPGA work, then "all" you need to do is build a SHA implementation, some method of getting data to and from it and a little control logic.  I haven't done it myself, but I got about that far along a "thought-design" before deciding I wasn't sufficiently interested to pursue it further.

Comment: The idea is to learn, not to mine. I have already done some work with FPGA, like playing a song and working with colour. Have you tried to mine with FPGA?

Comment: There is a laptop-integrable FPGA board [here](https://www.crowdsupply.com/rhs-research/nanoevb#products-top), could you learn FPGA with it and also some bitcoin mining?