# How to begin FPGA mining

Tags: mining-hardware, fpga

Since I own two FPGA:s I want to get started mining. It doesn't matter which currency I am mining, only that it works. I would prefer to do mining of Bitcoin, Ether, Dash or LItecoin but anything that works with my FPGA will do.

My FPGAs are Altera DE2 and Altera DE2-115. I already checked out one project that was too old (it used the `getwork` call which has been deprecated.

Any suggestions what I should do? I know C programming and some electronics and VHDL so I can find my way around a complicated installation or building it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5481/how-to-start-mining-with-fpga ?

Comment: @MeshCollider please, that question is five years old and any specific technology mentioned in there is likely outdated and deprecated.

Comment: The information contained in the answer is non-specific to any particular FPGA or currency, its more of a general introduction to getting started. But I assume then that you are looking for specific software to install on yours

Comment: @MeshCollider Yes please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a total newbie but so far the problem appears to be solvable. This is what I did with my Altera DE2-115 hooked-up to a Windows 7 machine:

1. got [fpgaminer's open source FPGA bitcoin miner on Github](https://github.com/fpgaminer/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner)
2. got [mining proxy on bitcoin.cz](https://mining.bitcoin.cz/mining-proxy-howto)
3. set up an account with [slushpool.com](https://slushpool.com/home/) (had to use VPN because my ISP apparently blocks connections to slushpool over http :((( )
4. registered an online BTC wallet with [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/)
5. updated `config.tcl` to connect to `localhost:8332` port and reflect my slushpool-related credentials
6. downloaded miner's bitstream into DE2-115
7. launched mining proxy
8. and finally ran `mine.bat`

**Illustration:** FPGA miner accepting jobs via Stratum rather than thru `getwork` protocol

[image: FPGA miner accepting jobs via Stratum]

The hashrate was indeed around 50 Mh/sec but after ~10 seconds the Cyclon IV chip got rather hot, so I decided to play it safe and stopped mining. As the next step I'm planning to install an active cooling system to continue experiments such as switching from my Windows rig to Raspi, mining altcoins, etc.

Comment: I just want to add to this guide that in 2021 this doesn't work as getwork() is no longer supported by slushpool. I just tried it out of curiosity to see if I could do it :)